# Gems available in Rails for online payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I wanted to know that how many gems are available for online payment in rails.
And also wanted to know that which one is easy to use and simple.
I have been using ActiveMerchant gem.

Answer (score 4):

ActiveMerchant is it :) and its fairly simple to use as well

Answer (score 0):

Try searching [here](http://rubygems.org) with "checkout" or similar keywords.

Answer (score 0):

[ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Payments) gives some insight for the most downloaded payment system. Active merchant obvious leader.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is one of the best which has a developer-friendly API. It hasn't any additional fees and the price you have to pay is less than PayPal. You can use its gem by adding "gem 'stripe'" to your gem file. More info: [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails)